# Why the object returned is Enumerable?

Tags: ruby, object, sinatra

I don't understand why do I get an Enumerable instead of an object. When I run this code :

```
 - @posts.each do |post|
    = Comment.find(id: post.id).title
```

I've got this error :

> undefined method `title' for  #Enumerator: Comment:find({:id=>1})>

If I check in the console I get also Enumerator :

```
[2] pry(#<Sinatra::Application>)> Comment.find 1
 => #<Enumerator: ...>
```

I just want to have my object like `#<Comment @id=1 @content="great" @post_id=1>`

I'm working with Sinatra and Datamapper.

Comment: Are you sure you are working with Datamapper? I'm asking since Datamapper doesn't define a `find` method on models. ActiveRecord does however, as does Sequel.

Comment: This is the first time I use datamapper. I thought that methods to call an object were the same, this is maybe the problem actually !

Comment: See http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html for some documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The query you're looking for is:

```
Comment.first(id: post.id).title
```

Which is a short version of:

```
Comment.all(id: post.id).first.title
```

There is no `find` in Datamapper (that I know of). What you're actually seeing is the result of Ruby's Enumerable#find: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find, which must be a part of Datamapper objects.